# Duplicate files in Xcode manager?

Tags: ios, xcode, file-management

I've found that I get duplicate files in the Xcode manager. They appear to point the same file in finder. My first thought is that this was created when one of my colleges was, incorrectly, fixing a conflict in the source control. I'm not sure how to fix the problem. When I try simply deleting a duplicate Xcode crashes. I've filed this buy with apple. However I would like to remedy this problem in the meantime.

Thank You.

[image: Xcode Manager]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what method you used to "delete the duplicate" (delete reference or Move to Trash)?

Comment: I tried to delete reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any duplicates in your list.  Every class comes with a .h and a .m file (there are exceptions).  Long story short, there's not a problem with the image you posted.

Comment: CMGoal.h, CMGoal.M, CMFund.h, CMFund.m, CMPortfolioPlan.h & CMPortfolioPlan.m all have duplicates.

Comment: Ah sorry!  I see!  I'd say that most likely you are going to have to manually merge them into one file.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of the `CMPortfolio.h` files and one of the `CMPortfolio.m` files (one of the references, rather) and press the delete key. When asked whether you want to remove the references or actually move the files to the Trash, choose `Remove References`. This should remove the duplicate references while not touching the actual files on disk (which allows the remaining reference to each file to be valid).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That helped me: I moved all duplicated files in some other folder in Finder -> all files in project were red. Then I simply deleted the files from project, copied the files in the project folder and added them to project again.